# VueJS 2, router guard

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

My index route is defined as:

```
{ path: '/', adminOnly: false, component: Main },
```

Is there a way to access the 'adminOnly' property?

There seems to be no way of doing so in this block of code:

```
routes.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    console.log(to)
    next();
});
```

My routes file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

import Main from '../components/Main.vue';
import About from '../components/About.vue';

const NotFoundException = {
    template: '<div>Route Was Not Found</div>'
};

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    hashbang: false,
    linkActiveClass: 'active',
    base: '/jokes',
    routes: [
        { path: '/', adminOnly: false, component: Main },
        { path: '/about', adminOnly: false, component: About },
        { path: '*', adminOnly: false, component: NotFoundException }
    ]
});
routes.mode = 'html5';

routes.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // CHECK IF ADMINONLY EXISTS
    next();
});

export default routes;
```

I did get a solution by adding a mixin of adminOnly.js which has the following code in it:
But then again, the mixin has to be added to each component if I was to redirect the user to the login page if not admin.
//Just a test
         var isAdmin = false;

```
export default {
        beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
            if(!isAdmin) {
                next((vm) => {
                   vm.$router.push('/login');
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there is better way to handle this. Every route object can have `meta` field. Just wrap `adminOnly` property in meta object:

```
 routes: [
        { path: '/', meta: { adminOnly: false }, component: Main },
        { path: '/about', meta: { adminOnly: false }, component: About },
        { path: '*', meta: { adminOnly: false }, component: NotFoundException }
    ]
```

Check route for admin rights:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.adminOnly)) {
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    // if not, redirect to login page.
  }
}
```

For more please check [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html) and I created little example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z03b853o/2/)

Comment: You have a typo: `record.meta.requiresAuth` in `beforeEach()` hook, should be `record.meta.adminOnly` in this case.

Comment: In docs they have a property named `requiresAuth` on meta object, while the OP question here uses `adminOnly` instead, so as it  is, your hook wouldn't be working.